# Change drupal font color based on variables

Tags: javascript, theming

I had a content type=score
This "score" content type had "field 1", "field 2" in integer.
Can I customize the font color based on variables.

ex:
when the users fill in <50 then show red color, 
When the users fill 50-70 then show orange color, 
When the users fill >70 then show green color.

Any contributed modules can do that function? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve this with jQuery.

In a custom module add the following code.

```
function custommodule_form_alter(&$form,$form_state,$form_id) {
  if ($form_id == "yourcontent type form") {
    $form['field_field1']['#attributes'] = array('id' => 'field1_id');
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'custommodule') . '/jsfilename.js', ));    
  }
}
```

Put this in jsfilename.js.

```
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.custommodule = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      // I suppose your field1 html elemet ID=field1_id
      $('#field1_id').change(function() {
        if($('#field1_id').val() < 50) {
          $(this).css("color","yellow"); // you can add class to it and in css file style it  ex:$(this).addClass('class1');
        }
        else if($('#field1_id').val() > 50 && $('#field1_id').val() < 70) {
          $(this).css("color","red");
          $(this).css("color","yellow"); // you can add class to it and in css file style it  ex:$(this).addClass('class1');
        }
        // …  
      });
    }
  }
}
```